# "Show me" type cout class C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, operator-overloading, cout

I am trying to create my own version of a `cout <<` type of class. My goal is to make this class so that I can have a way of doing error checking at certain points like an assert but instead of only prompting when there is something wrong I want it to display based on the boolean variable that is manually set in `int main()` in the program that it is being used in.

Say for example you wanted to know what a certain data type or variable was a a certain point in program, you would want to do a `cerr <<` statement to check it right? But what if you don't want to have to go in and comment out or delete those `cerr <<` statements every time you wanted to run a clean program? What the `showMe <<` class would do is determine whether or not the programmer wants to check for those errors that have been placed with a boolean variable as mentioned before. Then if the variable was `true` it would display all those `showMe <<` statements within the command line code. If it is `false` then it would ignore those statements.

Is this possible? I feel like my biggest hangup is how to recreate the classic `cout <<` statement so I can edit it to my design. Can anyone recommend how to go about this? I don't have any code developed yet.

Thanks!

Comment: "The `cout <<` statement" is just operator overloading. (It's secretly a left shift operator)

Comment: You can easily do this with a macro. However, there might be better options, so I am hesitant to post that as an answer. I suggest looking at how assert works: https://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/examples/assert_8h-source.html

Comment: The problem is I don't want it to act like an assert. I want to be able to type something like `showMe << "The x value here is: " << x << endl;` and only have it display if the programmer has set the boolean part of the class to true manually at the very beginning of `int main()`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Instead of creating a new class (from ostream as base class in particular). If you just have the simple goal that you mentioned, a preprocessor directive (aka macro) for compile time or an 'if' statement in a runtime function that returns cout object back will function for you.

If you really want to use a class, just override the '<<' operator.

Comment: @WilliamKappler: macros are best for this - they let you automatically capture the source code filename, line number, and function name, as well as stringified versions of arguments that can be used in the diagnostic messages.  Might as well post....

Comment: How do you want `showMe << feedTheChildren();` to behave when the user has disabled logging?

Comment: @Tylersong55: try `#define SHOWME(MSG) if (g_verbose) std::cerr << "at line " << __LINE__ << ": " << MSG << '\n'; else`, where `bool g_verbose;` is a global variable that you can change based on your command line arguments, then you can write `SHOWME("x is " << x);` etc..  Another benefit of using macros is that you can avoid evaluating arguments that might be time consuming.  You could even have `#define SHOWVAR(X) if (g_verbose) std::cout << #X " is " << X << '\n'; else`, so you automatically have the variable name in the message.

Comment: @TonyD: I don't personally understand macros with how to make them. Where would a macro be in the organization of my files? Can you explain to me how they work or give me a link to go off of?

Comment: You could put either of the `SHOWME` macros above on the very first line of any of your source files, but if multiple header files do so you may get harmless compiler warnings about duplicate definitions - to avoid those put `#ifndef SHOME` on the first line, then `#define SHOWME <as above>` on the second, then `#endif` on the third.  Alternatively, create a distinct header with `#pragma once` on the first line, and `#define SHOWME <as above>` on the second, and include it from whichever files want to use the macro.  For these multi-file situations, you will need `extern bool g_verbose;` too.

Comment: Specifically, one translation unit (e.g. main.cpp) should *define* `bool g_verbose;` at global scope, but other translation units need to be told it exists, so add the `extern bool g_verbose;` immediately after the `SHOWME` definition.